# why my import scapy.all is not working at all?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, scapy, python-venv

My scapy is not working at all. I don't know what the problem. I already install "pip install scapy" but it still persists in not working. I install the scapy in my pyserver/venv/Scripts. Im using windows for my laptop.

```
from scapy.all import *
ip = IP()
ip.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\1luki\pyserver\scapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
  File "c:\Users\1luki\pyserver\scapy.py", line 1, in <module>
    from scapy.all import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scapy.all'; 'scapy' is not a package
```

[Scapy error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dAxe.png)

Comment: "c:\Users\1luki\pyserver\scapy.py": You called this file `scapy.py`, which means your script is trying to import itself. Rename this script to something else.

Comment: thx I just realized it. I was so sleepy and I didn't realize I named it scapy.